# Is there a speed difference in 'if' functionizing for readability in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, function, if-statement

For example.

```
bool IsPlayerOutMap()
{
    bool t = (Player.x < 0 || Player.y < 0
        || Player.x > 1000 || Player.y > 1000);
    return t;
}

if(IsPlayerOutMap())
    cnt++;
```

and

```
if((Player.x < 0 || Player.y < 0
        || Player.x > 1000 || Player.y > 1000))
    cnt++;
```

Is there any speed difference in two coding style?

Comment: No. The function here is trivially inlineable.

Comment: I love micro-optimization. Why not just measure it?

Comment: Any half-decent compiler should inline the function and generate the same executable code for it.  There's a pair of unnecessary parentheses in the second block of code though.

Comment: It it is inlined, it should perform the same. If it isn't, the function will be a couple a few ns slower. There are some compiler options that could prevent the function from being inlined like if you're compiling a shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically for failed "if" you have a performance penalty. since CPU has execution pipes (it start to executes next asm commands before previous has ended), when you enter a "if" the CPU branch prediction (you can read about that) chose to execute one of the paths (the if result is "true" or "false") and if it is wrong then the exec stops in the middle (replaces the commands with NOP - no operation) and start the other path, here you lose performance.

in your code the "if" code and logical statement are equal more or less (you can read about "if short cut" to understand why). however, calling another function might matter here. unlike what was said in the comments the compiler will not always put it inline (unless you specify with flags) and even then in some cases the inlined code is longer and then you can get more cache thrashing (you can read about it) in the instruction cache.

this is micro-optimization like said, and the best way to decide here is with profiler. such small optimization from my experience matters only in very specific cases, for example router that process 10M packets per second and than every nano matters.

another point. it is a better code style to always add braces around "if" code. it doesn't impact performance.